# Open windows file/folder properties dialog from C

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have this tiny programm, which is intened to show windows file/folder properties dialog on the specified `info.lpFile`:

```
#include <windows.h>

main() {
   SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};

   info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
   info.lpFile = "C:\\test.txt";
   info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
   info.fMask = 0x00000000;
   info.lpVerb = "properties";

   ShellExecuteEx(&info);
}
```

When I compile and execute it, I get the following error message:

[image: Error message]

I'm using Win7 and Mingw gcc compiler. Does anybody knows what is wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

Comment: You might try `SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST` for `fMask`.

Comment: I tried, but the program just hangs with this mask.

Comment: Your code misses to initialise (the rest) of `info`

Comment: `info.lpVerb` should be "open" or `0`, I don't think "properties" is valid. Also you should put `SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: It is valid. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and

Comment: When `info.lpVerb` is "open" or "edit", everything works just fine, but I need windows properties dialog and the value "properties" is acceptable, according the msdn documentation. I edited my question by adding `SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};` but nothing has changed in the behavior of the program.

Comment: I see, add `Sleep(1000)` at the end of the code and use alk's suggestion `SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST`, also you have to initialize to zero.

Comment: Very well, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  When declaring the main() function, there are (ignoring the optional environment parameter) just 2 valid and one optional ways to declare main().  they all have a return type of 'int'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1st of all the code as shown does not properly initialise `info`.

To fix this change

```
  SHELLEXECUTEINFO info;
```

to be

```
  SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};
```

---

2ndly use `SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST` for `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`'s member `fMask`.

For your reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Please note that to see the properties window open, the invoking code must not end immediately. So add something like

```
  Sleep(10000);
```

to the end of your test code as shown.

---

Full code that works for me:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) 
{
  SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};

  info.cbSize = sizeof info;
  info.lpFile = L"C:\\tmp\\tmp.txt";
  info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
  info.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
  info.lpVerb = L"properties";

  ShellExecuteEx(&info);

  Sleep(10000);
}
```

Build options:

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\SOxyzConsoleEmpty.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

*(Tested with VS2010, running Windows 7)*

Comment: do you mean it worked for you with this mask? For me, it hangs, and nothing else.

Comment: if the user closes the opened file properties dialog, the C program still executes because of long lasting `Sleep()`. How can I terminate the execution of the C program when the properties dialog is closed?

Comment: @polis Good question: An untested proposal: Pass your application's parent window's handle via `info`'s member `hwnd` and make the window identified by this handle aware the `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` message. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Pass the SEE_MASK_NOASYNC (0x00000100) flag in your SHELLEXECUTEINFO to tell ShellExecuteEx that you're calling it without a message loop and not to return until it has finished.

See the remarks in the SHELLEXECUTEINFO docs on MSDN at https://wmsdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784(v=vs.85).aspx

Sleep() is neither necessary nor recommended.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT: Sorry, that's not that simple. I'm calling `ShellExecuteEx` with exact same parameters as above, except I also added `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);` and it works. If I add `info.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;` it does not. In that case `ShellExecuteEx` returns immediately, as if no_async flag was not used and after a while I get a messagebox with the error `The properties for this item are not available.` I'm calling it from a GUI 64-bit application without a message loop. Opening properties for a 64-bit executable.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I am trying to get rid of the `Sleep` as well

Answer (score -1):

I'd start by initializing info:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};
```

Then, I'd try a verb that actually exists in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell`

```
info.lpVerb = "open";
```

Which I strongly suspect will work. The problem is, explorer does not launch an application to show the properties of files - its built in. Not every piece of functionality on a file context menu is a verb that you can invoke via ShellExecute.

If you want to invoke the properties context menu item for a file - you will need to query for the `IShellFolder` that represents the files folder, call `GetUIObjectOf` to get the `IContextMenu` for the file, which you can then call `InvokeCommand` on.

See [Getting Information About the Contents of a Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776885(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN for information.

Comment: The guy wants to open the file's properties (dialogue) not the file itself.